# running multiple Entity Framework commands one by one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, package-manager-console

Is it possible to run scripts in Package manager Console to update Entity Framework with multiple commands?
I'd want a script like:

```
Update-database -migration oldTragetMigration
remove-migration
remove-migration
add-migration newMigration
update-database
```

I want to be able to run the script in sequences so that I don't have to wait for each step to take place?

Not even sure if I can write a c# script for that kind of thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can always add new file in your project (`right click on project -> Add New Item -> Text file`), and name it, for example

```
script.ps1
```

Edit it, put your commands inside, save. Open Package Manager Console and run it. You will  need to specify path, like this:

```
.\[project folder]\script.ps1
```